# Event sourcing : updating an event data

Tags: events, cqrs, event-sourcing

i'm stuggling with one scenario in the event sourcing.
i have and order picking system which allows to prepare orders.
i registered order prepared event with pickedQuantity > requestedQuantity
i'm asking how can i add this control on my source code to prevent this situation, how can i also refresh all the orders affected in order to be able rebuild the correct state ?

Any idea please ?

this is how it was my source code before

```
handle(OrderPrepared event) {
 OrderLine orderLine = event.getData();
 this.pickedQuantity = orderline.getPickedQuantity();
}
```

after adding the control to fix the issue

```
handle(OrderPrepared event) {
 OrderLine orderLine = event.getData();
if(orderline.getPickedQuantity <= ordeline.getRequestedQuantity) {
 this.pickedQuantity = orderline.getPickedQuantity();
 }
}
```

doing this way, will block rebuilding the aggregate state to append other events

Answer (score 1):

> i'm stuggling with one scenario in the event sourcing.

Not your fault; the literature sucks[tm].

---

> i'm asking how can i add this control on my source code to prevent this situation

So normally the enforcement of business *policy* belongs in your "command handlers" - aka the logic that decides what events you add to your history, and what information those events contain.

When policy was applied incorrectly (or when policies change), we normally bring the data back into conformance with policy bad adding more events to the history to correct the problems.  This is properly thought of as implementing the corrective processes of the actual problem domain.

For example, in an accounting domain when you have an error in an entry, there is a procedure for introducing a line item that reverses the error and a second line item that has the correct information.  So you would implement that process in a command handler that appends the events to the history.

(Sorry: I don't know enough about order picking systems to know how domain experts would reverse the error you describe.  It might be as simple as deleting that order line and then adding the corrected version.  Depending on your local context, that might be one event or two).

---

You should not, as a rule, be trying to apply policy when reading a sequence of events.  In particular, we shouldn't be blocked from loading a history into memory when we want to fix errors in that history!

Therefore, when copying information into your transient in-memory representations, you should be treating the provided history as authoritative.

Trying to rewrite history on the fly, so to speak, is not a problem you want to have when you are just getting started.  (See [Greg Young's book](https://leanpub.com/esversioning) if you have that problem anyway.)

---

That said, there's nothing necessarily wrong with using values computed from the information that is in your events.

"When generating Bob's Monday report, column seven should show the minimum of the pickedQuantity and the requestedQuantity (or zero, whichever is greater)" is a perfectly reasonable requirement to meet using an events as your data model, you can just do that.

You just need to do it well enough that the next programmer to come along (who might be you, months from now when you've forgotten the subtle details) can quickly understand what's happening and extend the code to meet new needs without unnecessary risk.

Comment: adding events to fix issues may lead to understandble domain. also, in my use case i should to fix an item preparation when the order is already delivered (actually i can't touch the order when it's delivered)